# Drupal mod rewrite directory to query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, drupal-7, directory, query-string

I've seen this question asked/answered a few times on stackoverflow, but I can't get any of the solutions to work for me.  I'm sure it's a case of my misunderstanding how mod rewrite works.

I'm trying to rewrite:

node/45/done/sid/
to 
node/45/done?sid=

I'm using Drupal, so there are already a few mod rewrite entries (see belo) that might be interfering with the other solutions I've seen.  For whatever solves above, where I should put this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the normal "RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]" rule has the [L] flag, no more rules will execute after that one.  So you'll need to add your rules before that one.  The "RewriteRule "(^|/)." - [F]" line is a safety precaution, so I'd add your rule immediately after that.  I believe if you don't add the [L] flag to your rule, it will then fall through to the default rule.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Where to put it is answered, now I just need to figure out the how - specifically the syntax needed to do the redirect